# R wordcloud2 showing blank page - persistent problem

Tags: r

I have the exact same problem as previously asked May 3 '18.

wordcloud2 performs fine until I try to add a mask. The code executes fine  in RMarkdown with no error but also produces only a blank page.
Previous suggestions were to re-install wordcloud2 which I did. However, this did not resolve of the problem.

```
# works fine gives word cloud with red palette
wordcloud2(hmtTable, 
           size = 0.7, 
           color = rep_len(redPalette, nrow(hmtTable)))  


# produces blank page, heart.png is in subdirectory figs
wordcloud2(hmtTable, 
           size = 1.5, 
           figPath = "figs/heart.png", 
           color = rep_len(redPalette, nrow(hmtTable)))
```

This  code should have produced a word cloud in shape of mask shape. It did not, and no error message was given.

Comment: Can you create a basic [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) where the error occurs? As it stands now we don't have htmTable. You could use `dput(htmTable)` and copy the output of this if it isn't to big (or data sensitive).

Comment: # example
esc1 <- search_tweets(
    "#esccongress OR #esccongress2019", n = 18000, include_rts = FALSE
)
hmtTable <- esc1 %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, text)
data(stop_words)

hmtTable <- hmtTable %>%
    anti_join(stop_words)

wordcloud2(hmtTable, size=0.7) # works fine

wordcloud2(hmtTable, size=0.7, shape = "star") # works fine

wordcloud2(hmtTable, size=1.5, figPath = "figs/heart.png") # blank output despite heart.png file existing, no error

Comment: I hope this code is properly formatted I tried to follow the rules of using 4 spaces but it sure doesn't look right

Comment: I wrote my own code as I don't want to use twitter :-). I can see that the wordcloud2 is indeed not creating the expected output. I checked with package ggwordcloud based on the ggplot2 framework. That one does create the wordclouds in all the shapes you feed to it. You might want to check that one out. The vignette with it provides all the examples you need.